# WCAG compliant forms - Is cancel button required

Tags: forms, button, accessibility, wcag

I am making WCAG 2 AA compliant web forms (e.g. feedback form), and was wondering if anyone knew if a Cancel button was required as a part of WCAG?

I have looked all over the place, and I can't find anything specific relating to its appearance (I assume this is because its not required).

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I do not believe you need to have a specific Cancel button as part of a form to be WCAG2 AA compliant.

I don't really know how to embellish this answer with references etc, since I cannot find a specific reference to point to.  Proving a negative is rather hard, but in my experience this is not something that is considered.

That said, good accessibility tends to go hand-in-hand with good user experience.  This Ux question tends to point to Cancel being used [sparingly in web applications in general](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/is-a-cancel-button-necessary-in-a-web-form).

If in doubt, and if you cannot find a specific guidance, as yourself whether the functionality you are delivering [Perceivable, Operable, Understandable and Robust](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) ... if you can say yes to these, then the chances are your design choice is in the right direction.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Your response is definitely the way I'll be going!

Answer (score 2):

**No, the WCAG guidelines do not require a 'cancel button'.**

WCAG dictate relatively few specific actions for a webpage, and focuses more on how those actions are presented. An example of where an action is dictated is a users ability to stop or stow moving text.

The key to focus on is from the opening line:

> Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 defines how to make Web content more accessible to people with disabilities.

So, when aiming to meet WCAG compliance, focus on the actions all users may need and how a disabled user may be presented with difficulties.

Also, its worth pointing out WCAG dictates no policy about user interfaces and user experience. A bad user interface can be WCAG compliant, as long as it meets the WCAG guidelines.

For example, a light gray `Cancel` button on a gray background with a small font *would not* be WCAG compliant for contrast and size reasons. However, a lack of `cancel` button that provided a user no way to stop an action *would* be WCAG compliant as it isn't violating any rules.

Comment: Thanks for your response, definitely useful information.